# Not receiving UDP multicast in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am trying to use udp multicast, and am running the same code on a windows machine and an ubuntu machine. The moment i remove the ip in socket.bind(), i am able to receive the data send from the windows machine to the ubuntu machine. Note that i am using the correct ip on the ubuntu machine, not 192.168.0.7. The data sent from the ubuntu machine to the windows machine is also received. What is the reason for this?

```
const argon2 = require('argon2');
const dgram= require('dgram');
let ip = '192.168.0.7';
let securityLevel = 1, isHashPopulated = false;
let publicKey = null;
let hashPromise = argon2.hash('somekey');
if(securityLevel === 1 && !isHashPopulated) {
    hashPromise.then(hash => {
        isHashPopulated = true;
        publicKey = hash;
    });
}
const socket = dgram.createSocket({ type: 'udp4' });
socket.on('message', (msg, rinfo) => {
    if(rinfo.address !== ip) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(msg.toString()));
    }
});
socket.bind(3000, ip, () => socket.setBroadcast(true));
socket.on('listening', () => {
    socket.addMembership('224.0.255.255');
    setInterval(() => {
        if((publicKey !== null && securityLevel === 1) || securityLevel > 1) {
            const data = JSON.stringify({ testdata: 'this is test data', key: publicKey });
            socket.send(data, 0, data.length, 3000, '224.0.255.255');
        }
    }, 1000);
});
socket.on('error', err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Note that uni/multicast is not send over all network interfaces.

Comment: @Marc i confirmed using tcpdump that the data was being sent, but none being recieved. I also confirmed that the wireless card had multicast capabilities.

Comment: Can i strip code a litle bit down, e.g. remove the hash stuff & reduce it to the simplest udp multicast stuff ? Then i will investigate the problem an a solution

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine:

```js
const dgram = require("dgram");

// ignore messages from this addresses
const addresses = [
    "127.0.0.1",
    "192.168.2.111"
];


// fake publicKey
let publicKey = Date.now();
const address = "224.0.255.255";


// create underlaying network socket
const socket = dgram.createSocket({
    type: "udp4"
});


// bind socket to port
socket.bind(3000);



// listen for messages
socket.on("message", (data, rinfo) => {
    if (!addresses.includes(rinfo.address)) {

        // feedback
        console.log("> received multicast:", rinfo, data.toString());

    }
});


// socket ready ?!
socket.on("listening", () => {

    // socket stuff
    //socket.setBroadcast(true);
    socket.addMembership(address);

    // send message in 1s interval
    setInterval(() => {

        // create message
        const data = JSON.stringify({
            testdata: "this is test data",
            key: publicKey
        });

        // feedback
        console.log("Send multicast >", data);

        // send udp message
        socket.send(data, 0, data.length, 3000, address);

    }, 1000);

});


// listen for socket errors
socket.on("error", err => {

    // feedback
    console.log(err);

});
```

Tested with:

- Workstations, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (LAN)
- Laptop, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (WLAN)
- Laptop, Windows 10, 1909 (WLAN)

Let me know if you have any issues with it.

EDIT: Alternative you can add this snippet to create the `addresses` array dynamic:

```js
const os = require("os");
const interfaces = os.networkInterfaces();

for (let key in interfaces) {

    let ips = interfaces[key].filter((iface) => {
        return iface.family === "IPv4" && iface.internal === false;
    }).map((iface) => {
        return iface.address;
    });

    addresses.push(...ips);

}

console.log(addresses);
```